# How to open android activity from react native

Tags: android, react-redux, react-native

I want to open android native module from react native in the blank space shown in the figure

[image]

But it is opening a new activity instead of showing on the same activity.

**Here is my react native code**

```
MyNativeModule.nativeModule(data);
```

**Below is my MyNativeModule.java**

```
public class MyNativeModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public MyNativeModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void nativeModule(String token){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getReactApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data", data.toString());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        getReactApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MyNativeModule";
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you try to create another activity and then start the activity with same pattern?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed But how will that solve my problem? it will open a blank activity first and then open the required one

Comment: In the beginning, MainActivity started first. That's mean you already on the MainActivity. For more information you can visit this tutorial: https://github.com/petterh/react-native-android-activity

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Have you find any solution?